# AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'year' in a TimeStamp

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, apply

I have a dataframe with a column called `CRASH TIME`, containing a datetime object, but due to the import it now contains, according to `df.info()`, a Series of dtype `object`.

I'm trying to create a column containing the date of Christmas for each year in that Series using an `apply()` function:

```
df.apply(lambda x: dt.datetime(x['CRASH TIME'].year,12,25), axis=1)
```

This produces an error `AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'year'`.
So, with an `x['CRASH TIME']` object of type `numpy.float64`, I decided to try:

```
df.apply(lambda x: dt.datetime(x['CRASH TIME'].astype('datetime64').year,12,25), axis=1)
```

This now produces an error `AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'astype'`. It seems that it's recognized as either a `float64` or a TimeStamp, and it can't seem to decide which, making it difficult to diagnose or properly `apply()`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: what is the timestamp like?

Comment: "It seems that it's recognized as either a float64 or a TimeStamp, and it can't seem to decide which" Think carefully about what "it" means in your claim. The point of `.apply` is that you are using the same logic with multiple different values. Have you considered that they might not all be the same type? You should probably fix that.

Comment: @ewong `df.loc[0, 'CRASH TIME']` provides me with `Timestamp('2017-06-26 22:00:00')`.

Comment: When you say "due to the import", what code are you actually referring to? Did you not think it strange that the type of your DataFrame's column changed? The point of `object` as a `dtype` is that it can store anything, including mix-and-matched data - such as, oh, say, `numpy.float64`s mixed with `Timestamp`s.

Comment: "`df.loc[0, 'CRASH TIME']` provides me with..." Okay; and how about `df.loc[1, 'CRASH TIME']`? `df.loc[2, 'CRASH TIME']`? Do you see the issue?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I get what you're saying, and it seems that your above comment was right. It hadn't occurred to me to check that because I had written in a `datetime` transformation earlier in my code.  I'll have to go back and check what went wrong with that. It otherwise works now, thanks for the guidance on thinking carefully about what "it" means.

Comment: did you mean `df['CRASH TIME'].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime(x.year,12,25), axis=1)`? (assuming ['CRASH TIME'] is a column of dtype datetime64)